# Find missing value in table from given set

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there is a table called "allvalues" with a column named "column".
This column contains the values "A" to "J" while missing the "H".

I am given a set of values from "G" to "J".

How can I query the table to see which value of my set is missing in the column?

The following does not work:

```
select * from allvalues where column not in ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
```

This query would result in `A, B, C, D, E, F, H` which also contains values not included in the given set.

Obviously in such a small data pool the missing value is noticeable by eye, but imagine more entries in the table and a bigger set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with a (derived) table with the values you are checking.  One explicit method is:

```
with testvalues as (
      select 'G' as val from dual union all
      select 'H' as val from dual union all
      select 'I' as val from dual union all
      select 'J' as val from dual 
     )
select tv.val
from testvalues tv
where not exists (select 1 from allvalues av where av.column = tv.val);
```

Often, the values originate through a query or a table.  So explicitly declaring them is unnecessary -- you can replace that part with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which SQL syntax you can use, but basically you want to check your table allvalues + the extra values.

eg:

```
SELECT *                                 
FROM ALLVALUES                           
WHERE COLUMN NOT IN (                    
( select s.column from allvalues s )     
and column not in ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
    select * from table1;
    G
    H
    I
    J

    select * from table1
    minus
    (select * from table1
    intersect 
    select column from allvalues
    )
sample input:

select * from  ns_table10;
G
H
I
J
SELECT * FROM ns_table11;
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
J
I
select * from ns_table10
minus
(select * from ns_table10
intersect 
select * from ns_table11
);

output:
H
```